# Will divding a np.float64 object by 2 makes the return value's dtype np.float32?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

While I read some Tensorflow source code I found this:

```
  if tf_dtype.is_floating:
    if spec.dtype == np.float64 and np.any(np.isinf(high - low)):
      # The min-max interval cannot be represented by the np.float64. This is a
      # problem only for np.float64, np.float32 works as expected.
      # Spec bounds are set to read only so we can't use argumented assignment.
      low = low / 2  # pylint: disable=g-no-augmented-assignment
      high = high / 2  # pylint: disable=g-no-augmented-assignment
    return rng.uniform(
        low,
        high,
        size=spec.shape,
    ).astype(spec.dtype)
```

I am not very familiar with python. The codes above seem very interesting, it implies that when operation

```
 low = low / 2  
 high = high / 2
```

will make the new `low` and `high`'s dtype float32. But when I try this in the python terminal

```
>>> a = np.array([2.0], dtype=np.float64)
>>> a.dtype
dtype('float64')
>>> b = a/2
>>> b.dtype
dtype('float64')
```

Things don't look like so. The code source is [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/agents/blob/master/tf_agents/specs/array_spec.py), at line 42. Can anybody explain this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No.

This looks like a workaround for a problem with calculating the interval between minimum and maximum values in a np.float64 array. The tensorflow code does not return a np.float32, but calculates the correct value and returns it using the original type.

Also, from your snippet it looks the code you ran on the terminal uses pure numpy and doesn't go anywhere near the tensorflow library, so would not reproduce any strange behaviour from tensorflow.

Answer (score 0):

No. To rescale to a different data type, you can use *normalization*:

```
zero_to_one = np.divide(old_val/np.amax(old_val)) # normalizes to 0 - 1
new_range = zero_to_one * max_val_of_new_dtype
new_range = np.array(new_range, dtype='desired dtype')
```